# Нужна помощь при создание всплывающей подсказки на jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет, написал небольшой код для всплывающей подсказки

```
$(function(){
            var links = $('a[title]');
            links.hover(
            function(){
                var current = $(this);
                var tooltipText = current.attr('title');
                $('div class="tooltip"/div').hide().appendTo(current).text(tooltipText)
.fadeIn(500);
            },function(){
                $('div.tooltip').fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });
        });
```

Возникла одна проблема аттрибут title никуда не делся и браузер отображает дефолтную подсказку тоже при наведении на ссылку. Как можно передавать содержимое переменной tooltipText второй функции, чтобы можно было создать аттрибут title опять? И установить его с помощью attr('title',tooltipText )

Хтмл код самый простой - просто ссылка с аттрибутом title, таких ссылок на странице будет много.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var links = $('a[title]');
    links.hover(function(){
        var current = $(this);
        var tooltipText = current.attr('title');
        $('<div class="tooltip"></div>').hide().appendTo(current).text(tooltipText).fadeIn(500);
        current.removeAttr('title');
    }, function(){
        $('.tooltip', this).fadeOut(500, function(){
            $(this.parentNode).attr('title', this.innerHTML);
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Так сойдет? Хотя и тут я бы некоторые моменты переписал на чистом js...

Comment: Да Ваша концепция очень хорошая, правильно ведь нам не нужно ничего сохранять и передавать, мы можем вытащить содержимое дива и засунуть его в наш титле. Респект.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
            var links = $('a[title]');
    $('a[title]').each(function() { $(this).attr('rel', $(this).attr('title')); $(this).removeAttr('title') }).hover(
            function(){
                var tooltipText = $(this).attr('rel');
                $('<div class="tooltip"></div>').hide().appendTo($(this)).text(tooltipText)
.fadeIn(500).attr('rel', tooltipText);
            },function(){
                $('div.tooltip').fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });

    });
```

Может быть как-то так?

Comment: Это мы просто перезаписываем содержимое титле в аттрибут рел, а как сделать чтоб в момент ховер титле сохранялся в переменную и удалялся, а когда мышь уходит из области ссылки, вторая функция получала бы этот параметр и опять восстанавливала аттрибут титле. При этом большое спасибо, код полностью рабочий.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как я изменил скрипт (теперь все на jquery) и закрыл свой тикет. Всем большое спасибо!

```
$(function(){
            var links = $('a[title]');
            links.hover(
            function(){
                var current = $(this);
                var tooltipText = current.attr('title');
                $('<div class="tooltip"></div>').hide().appendTo(current).text(tooltipText).fadeIn(500);
                current.removeAttr('title');
            },function(){
                var tooltipDiv = $('div.tooltip');
                var tooltipText = tooltipDiv.text();
                $(this).attr('title', tooltipText);
                tooltipDiv.fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });

        });
```